# Does MS Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 compile C++11 raw string literals?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11

When Update 1 CTP back in November 2012 came out, several blogs and also channel9 video demonstrated raw literals as an added C++11 feature.

screen shot from:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/STLCCSeries6:

[image: screen shot from channel9 vid]

I updated VS2012 to Update2 (April 2013) and the version now shows 17.00.60315.1 but I get compilation errors:

[image: error C2065]

Was raw string support removed after the CTP or did I overlook something obvious?

Comment: Does your emacs look like a notepad or is it just me? :)

Comment: You know you can copy/paste *text*, right? You don't actually need to take a screenshot of the text you want to show us.

Comment: Yep.  That compilation test was done in a Virtual Machine that wasn't easily accessible at the moment to copypasta the text but I did have the screenshots.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The November CTP was not for Update 1, it was for "some unspecified future update".

Now Update 2 has been released, which contains *nothing* relevant to C++11.

The November CTP *might* eventually be released as Update 3.

Or it could be Update 4, or perhaps Update 14. Microsoft clearly isn't in a hurry. But outside of the CTP, these C++11 features are not yet supported by MSVC in Update 2 or earlier.

Comment: 1 more month until the Build conference to listen to what MS have to offer in 1H13...

Comment: @rhalbersma 1H13 will be over by then

Comment: Well, that makes sense!  I thought I was going crazy.  What's more confusing is that when you use google to search for November CTP, some of the pages then redirect you to April 2013 Update 2 which makes one believe the CTP is rolled up into it.

Comment: @JasDev November CTP is a separate branch of updates, solely targetting C++11 support. It includes a separate compiler, but not the other VS updates.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't. **Only Visual Studio 2013 supports raw string literals.**

Helpful link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx